# Is it best practice to always try to return a minimum number of rows from the database?

Tags: php, database, mysql

First-time poster so please be gentle :)

I have a rather large table in my database (MySQL in case it matters) that holds lat/lng values of certain points of interest around the world (table name: Maps). The table is very large (millions of rows) and could grow significantly larger since users can add rows to it.

I have another table called Users that also holds lat/lng values of user locations around the world. It is currently in the low thousands, and I wouldn't expect it to grow to more than a few tens of thousands.

My scenario is that I need to run a query that compares the lat/lng position of some users in the Users table against some locations in the Maps table and return locations less than a certain distance. The SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT x.type FROM Maps x INNER JOIN Ranges ON Ranges.type = x.type
        WHERE x.user_ID IN ($users)
        AND m.lat BETWEEN
        x.lat - Ranges.range AND
        x.lat + Ranges.range 
        AND m.lng BETWEEN
        x.lng - Ranges.vision_range * COS(RADIANS(x.lat)) AND
        x.lng + Ranges.vision_range * COS(RADIANS(x.lat))
        AND (6378137 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(x.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(m.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(m.lng) 
         - RADIANS(x.lng)) + SIN(RADIANS(x.lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(m.lat)))) < Ranges.range
```

This query is currently in production and works OK. It follows my normal practice (and I'm assuming "best" practice) of running the specific query in SQL to return only the result set we are interested in, a so-called "minimum" or if you like "accurate" result set. I then don't need to further process the result set and can return it to the user's front-end app. A usual query returns maybe 100-1,000 values, however due to the relatively complex mathematical calculations takes 300-600ms to complete. This isn't ideal, because it's a web front end and the lag is noticeable.

However, I've been experimenting with running a "dumb" query that simply uses a large bounding box to return all possible values within a range and then use PHP to do the mathematical processing. The SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT m.type
FROM Maps m
WHERE m.user_ID IN ($users)
AND m.lat BETWEEN $minLat AND $maxLat
AND m.lng BETWEEN $minLng AND $maxLng
```

This query returns results in 3-6ms! However, the result set is huge and can be tens of thousands of rows. PHP obviously has no issues with the mathematics and can process it in a negligible amount of time.

Is there any reason I should *not* process the data in PHP? Am I missing something here about the tradeoff between the massive reduction in query time versus the huge volume of data returned (most of which will be "thrown away")?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything.  **Software development is always an exercise in tradeoffs,** and I've seen many Crystal Cathedral architectures and "best practices" (justifiably) sacrificed on the altar of performance.

Comment: That said, it's possible that there's still some optimizations that could be done on that query.  My guess is that it's slow because it has to execute all of those math functions for each and every row in the maps/ranges join, maybe more than once.  Check your [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comments Robert. The query is as optimised as I and a database expert who I hired can make it. He was much more experienced with queries than I was and set up the correct indices etc. I could only get it to a few seconds, so 300ms seems pretty good to me! I think at this point further optimisation would involve a tradeoff in accuracy (e.g. grouping "users" together) which I do not want.

Comment: Then your new approach sounds like a good plan to me.  Just watch your memory usage.

Comment: Use what works. The people who use the data won't care how you got it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's a really good point - so there is a potential tradeoff that I may not have considered. I wasn't examining memory usage during my testing, only query time and CPU. I'll run more tests querying memory, but since PHP scripts take milliseconds to execute, I feel that even if memory increases significantly it would be for an insignificant amount of time - especially compared with the 300-600ms of almost complete CPU usage with the current solution.

Comment: Just for fun, did you try adding AND m.lat BETWEEN $minLat AND $maxLat
AND m.lng BETWEEN $minLng AND $maxLng to the full query

Comment: and please, never use variables directly in your query unless you want to get hacked. Look into parameters

Comment: Remember that you can use a simple query and process the data in a stored procedure without sending all the data through the network. Of course it depends on a lot of factor like the relative cpu capabilities of your database vs server, the network between server and database, the current bottlenet of your application

Comment: Also: comparing the 3ms without the "relatively complex mathematical calculations" against the 600ms is not fair. But you can measure the total application time and choose whatever is better for you. Anyway: Best practices are general recommendations that need to be adapted to the context. Do no feel bad if you need to break one or two.

Comment: I think I'd be speaking for a number of people when I say that the mathematical calculations here are anything but "complex", and there is no particular evidence here of the intervention of a "database expert". Apply the fast filter first to get the rows down from the millions to the tens of thousands, and *then* simply filter again with the slower but more precise filter which requires a calculation to be done. Use a with-clause or an intermediate table to structure things properly (and if necessary, to enforce a particular execution plan).

Comment: So many good comments and great answers! Made it very difficult for me to choose, but I'm going with @IMSoP for the more comprehensive reply and the considerations for and against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right not to take it for granted that a "best practice" is always in fact the best strategy. The important thing is to understand the reasons it's *usually* a good idea, and then make an informed decision whether those reasons apply to your case.

Reasons it's *usually* a good idea to put as much filtering as possible on the database include:

- Flexibility - the DBMS has complex logic to take advantage of indexes, change the order of operations, etc, rather than always following the same strategy.
- Combining multiple filters - an important consequence of the above is that having more WHERE clauses in a single query can lead to better performance, because the DBMS can decide which one will quickly eliminate the most rows, and not examine them further.
- Network transfer - transferring the full set of data from MySQL to PHP takes time and uses bandwidth.
- Memory - the DBMS can work with the data directly on disk, or manage memory as it sees fit; a PHP algorithm will likely have the entire data set in memory.

Reasons it might be sensible to put it in the application layer:

- The DBMS you're using doesn't have good facilities for the type of filter you want to apply. Your example shows you manually calculating distances for each row, which is not something the DBMS can optimise easily. If there is any GIS / Polygon support for MySQL, using that would probably give you a dramatic performance boost; if there isn't, it may be a good reason to hand the work to PHP.
- You know that most of the results will meet the conditions. If you need most of the rows anyway, the network and memory factors disappear, so you can look at pure speed of filtering. Be careful how you measure it though: how do the two different approaches scale to larger data sets? How well do they cope with multiple simultaneous requests?
- Your filters include complex business logic, and you want to be able to unit test them, which is easier in procedural code. (Hat tip to [Esben Skov Pedersen](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/424857/96713) for pointing that out.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good chance that evaluating the condition stops when the outcome is known. You have an expensive and precise filter, and a cheap and coarse filter. If you use the condition “coarse filter AND precise filter”, then you get the precise result, but the expensive filter will not be evaluated for everything, but just for the rows that pass the first filter.

(I really hope I’m wrong here or the database expert you hired is useless).

Another thing: it is quite likely that you can find a formula for distance that doesn’t require cosines.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely fine to use the database as a coarse filter. Remember there it is hard to do unit tests of database code so we don't want the query to be too complex.

If you are using most of the data you get back I think it's absolutely fine to ask for more data than you need. If you however ask for 5x-10x the data you actually need I would consider it a problem.

Also in your case it is sometimes good to give the databases a few hints meaning if you combine your two queries (you add AND m.lat BETWEEN $minLat AND $maxLat
AND m.lng BETWEEN $minLng AND $maxLng) to the full query the db could choose to get that data first, and then only do the complex operations on that small dataset, this could be optimal for query speed and data transfer, but however the query is quite complex and it might be better to get that into some code where it's easier to have unit tests.

Also read up on sql injections unless you want your site to get hacked: https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php